# raw() / cbreak() function In Linux linker error

Tags: linux

WHen I compile this code, it shows me linker error

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   int ch;

    raw();              /* Line buffering disabled  */
}
```

Compiler error:

```
/tmp/ccY9Bug1.o: In function `main':
raw.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `raw'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked that curses.h anf ncurses.h exists in /usr/include directory and there is even man page for raw on my linux system. 
Please tell me how to correct this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass "-lcurses" or "-lncurses" or something like that to the linker.

```
gcc foo.c -lcurses
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with curses or ncurses library:

gcc yourcode.c -lcurses -lncurses